# Background colour isn't taking full width

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my portfolio which has **three** section tags. I've declared a background colour for the whole body, however, I want different colours to take **full width** for the 2nd & 3rd section tags -- just like body background colour.

While I did try to achieve that using the below code, the background colour for both the section tags isn't taking full page width. Any help on this would be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Srujan Sagar</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Pacifico|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        Srujan Sagar
    </header>

    <section>
        <p class="main-content">
            Hello! I'm an India-based self-taught FrontEnd Developer.
            <br />
            <br /> I have a diverse set of skills, ranging from design, to HTML + CSS + Javascript, all the way to Django.
        </p>

        <img src="images/main_img.jpg" alt="my picture" width="140" class="logo" />

        <ul class="social-links">
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Srujan.SaGar" target="_blank">
                    <span class="fa fa-facebook-square" style="font-size:32px;color:#A63A50"></span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <span class="fa fa-github" style="font-size:34px;color:#A63A50"></span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <span class="fa fa-linkedin-square" style="font-size:32px;color:#A63A50"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <br /> <br />
        <p class="line"></p>
    </section>

<nav class="main-content">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section class="second-content">
  <h3>Hi there!</h3>
</section>
<section class="third-content">
  <h3>Hi there!</h3>
</section>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    /*background: url('../images/background_img.jp');*/
    background-color: #FFFAFB;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

header {
    font-family: 'Pacifico', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 90px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #A63A50;
  }
.main-content {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: #CA7989;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
.logo {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #CA7989;
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
.social-links {
    margin: 25px 30px 0 0;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #CA7989;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.line {
    max-width: 550px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top: 1px solid #CA7989;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #A63A50;
  background: #F5E6E6;
}

.second-content {
    background:#ebebeb;
    width: 100%;
    height: 465px;
}
.third-content {
  margin-top:-18px;
  background:#CA7989;
  width: 100%;
  height: 465px;
}
```

View the above code in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PmZmvX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body {
    /*background: url('../images/background_img.jp');*/
    background-color: #FFFAFB;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    /* set margin and padding 0*/
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
margin: 0;
```

on the body, it's the default margin.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe remove margin and padding from the body :

```
body {
    background-color: #FFFAFB;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `margin: 0;` to `body`to remove the default margin.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWdwaG

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this

```
background-size : cover;
```

in "body" of your CSS :

```
body {
      /*background: url('../images/background_img.jp');*/
      background-color: #FFFAFB;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
      background-size: cover;
}
```

then try removing margin and padding of your body and that should do it!

You should also take a look at this article : https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: The background-size isn't required ... 1. it's a color so is useless. 2.I'ts just the margin on the body ....

Comment: My bad @DaniP ! I saw this URL and thought it was about a future background image.

Comment: Well maybe you are right that's why I didn't downvoted this, could be later useful for OP don't delete it +1